# @Html.PagedListPager does not send page in query string

Tags: pagination, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on ASP.NET Core project and after I updated the project to .NET Core 2.2 an issue with pagination has аppeared. I am using X.PagedList library. 
In my view I have the correct number of pages but the problem is that when i try to access the second page for example, the page is not sent in the query string. 
This is my code in the view:

```
 @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.Products,
           page => Url.Action("ProductsByCategory",
           new { Model.CategoryId, page, Model.SubCategoryId }),
           new PagedListRenderOptions()
           {
             UlElementClasses = new List<string> { "pagination"},
             LiElementClasses = new List<string> { "page-item", "page-link"}
           })
```

This is my code in the service:

```
 public AllProductsViewModel GetProductsByCategory(Guid categoryId, int? page, Guid? subCategoryId = null)
    {
        var products = dbContext.Products
            .Where(p => p.CategoryId == categoryId && p.IsAvailable)
            .To<ProductViewModel>()
            .ToList();

        if (subCategoryId != null)
        {
            products = products.Where(p => p.SubCategoryId == subCategoryId).ToList();
        }

        var nextPage = page ?? 1;

        var allProducts = new AllProductsViewModel()
        {
            CategoryId = categoryId,
            SubCategoryId = subCategoryId,
            Products = products.ToPagedList(nextPage, 9)
        };

        return allProducts;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems a bug using X.PagedList in .Net Core 2.2 , please check the related threads on github :

https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList/issues/133

https://github.com/dncuug/X.PagedList/issues/131

So try to use `pageNumber` instead of `page` as a workaround .

Comment: That was the solution for the problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is down to a change in the way asp.net core 2.2 constructs its URLs. By default it now checks there's a matching endpoint in the application, and if there isn't, no href is outputted.

[Routing differences between asp.net core 2.2 and earlier versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing#differences-from-earlier-versions-of-routing)

I had pages already indexed by search engines that used the querystring ?page and I didn't want to have to include 301s to redirect ?page to ?pagenumber.

Instead, there's an option in startup where you can override this behaviour and allow X.PagedList to work still using page rather than pagenumber.

Where you add MVC disable the endpoint routing feature:

**opt.EnableEndpointRouting=false**

```
services.AddMvc(opt => opt.EnableEndpointRouting=false)
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```